# Is it possible to manually call android lifecycle methods?

Tags: android, android-activity

Can the android lifecycle methods be called manually or if you try that you will get an exception or something like that? If it is possible to call them manually without any problems will they run in order ? i.e. If I call on stop() while the activity is in the foreground, will onPause() run first as it should?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is never safe to manually call any `on` method - those are meant to be called only by the managing system.

Comment: So does this mean I can't call them manually at all or it's possible but will just most likely cause problems?

Comment: Java allows you to call them, but calling the `super` method of any lifecycle method will cause issues in ~all cases. If you have logic you want to run both in those callbacks and separately, you should make your own method that is called from both places.